# Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error; React.js: screen is blank or white while going to open it in browser by typing npm start

Tags: google-chrome

I have following error getting on cosole...

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)**

**Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error**

**Full of my browser screen is white and no data shwing**

Following is my manifest.json file

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Here is the link tag on my indext.html file

```
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

I have done lists of work but problem still remainung...

1. delete `node_modules` and `package.lock.json` file and run `npm install` in my terminal
2. add `crossorigin="use-credentials"` into link tag on indext.html of public folder
3. edited follwing object on `manifest.json`

   {
   "start_url": "./",
   "display": "standalone",
   "theme_color": "#000000",
   "background_color": "#ffffff"
   }

but nothing is solved yet....

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this type of error could come in terms of broken files or dependencies. In that case, the best option I do think so far is to restart your project with newly installing react and copy all those files into your new project from the past one.

And let's try and see what's gonna happen;

```
  npx  i create-react-app "create-new-one"
```

then

```
 cd "create-new-one"
```

finally, copy file and folders as in order or the way of structure in a way in new created one and have a look for starting

```
npm start
```

Now all the issues relating to manifest.json is to go away

Note: in my case, I did the same way just said and consequences, get removed out of that

Answer (score 0):

You can put manifest.json into public folder – the URL will be just

`<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />`

This location is preferred over static (or any other folder) since Next.js 9.1, when public folder support was introduced.

In my case this solved the error, here is the link where i have found this solution https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9621